# Heat Equation & Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

While studying the heat equation, I ran into the following exercise:

> Consider conservation of thermal energy $(2)$ for any segment of a one-dimensional rod $a\leq x\leq b$. By using the fundamental theorem of calculus,
>
> $$
> \frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=f(b),\tag{1}
> $$
>
> derive the heat equation $(3)$.

For this exercise, we have that

$$\begin{align}
\frac d{dt}\int_a^be(x,t)\,dx&=\varphi(a,t)-\varphi(b,t)+\int_a^bQ(x,t)\,dx,\tag{2}\\
c\rho\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}&=\frac\partial{\partial x}\left(K_0\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)+Q.\tag{3}
\end{align}$$

I do not know how to tackle this problem. Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Also, I do not understand why $(1)$ has a partial derivative when $f$ is a function of a single variable.

**Edit 1**: Following celtschk's advice, I managed to rewrite $(2)$ as

$$
\frac d{dt}\int_a^be(x,t)\,dx=\varphi(a,t)-\frac\partial{\partial b}\int_a^b\varphi(x,t)\,dx+\int_a^bQ(x,t)\,dx.
$$

Now, I suppose that I must get rid of the $\partial/\partial b$ and subtract $\varphi(a,t)$?

**Edit 2** One could also rewrite $(2)$ as

$$
\frac d{dt}\int_a^be(x,t)\,dx= - \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_a^b \varphi(x,t) dx -\frac\partial{\partial b}\int_a^b\varphi(x,t)\,dx+\int_a^bQ(x,t)\,dx.
$$

using the fact that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_b^a \varphi(x,t) dx$. Is there a way to collect together the two terms with partial derivatives in order to get the desired $\int_a^b \frac{d \varphi}{dx} dx $ term in the heat equation?

Comment: Note that the whole expression on the left of (1) has *two* free variables (and none of them is $x$).

Comment: Yes, get rid of the derivative of $b$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Then you will have the difference is values of $\varphi$ at the endpoints a,b. Divide by $b-a$ and pass to the limit (or use the Mean Value theorem for differences and for integrals).

Comment: I presume $e(x,t)$ represents a heat density, $\varphi$ a flux, and $Q$ a rate of heat source term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me that you are seeking the derivation of the heat equation based on a conservation law type of argument. Let $u(x,t)$ denote the density of the quantity of interest (heat, diffusing ink, etc.), $\varphi(x,t)$ the flux (which in 1D is positive for rightward flow in 1D), and $q(x,t)$ the rate at which the quantity of interest is generated inside the domain (source/sink term).

Let $[a,b]$ be an arbitrary subinterval of the overall domain $[\alpha,\beta]$. The conservation law in force here is that *the time rate of change of the quantity in $[a,b]$ equals the rate of inflow at $x=a$ minus the rate of outflow at $x=b$ plus the amount of the quantity generated inside $[a,b]$.* That is,

$$
    {d\over dt}\int_a^b u(x,t)\,dx=\varphi(a,t)-\varphi(b,t)+\int_a^b q(x,t)\,dx.
$$
Pushing the time derivative inside the integral (this is justified here) and applying the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to the difference on the right-hand side,

\begin{align}
    \int_a^b {\partial u\over \partial t}(x,t)\,dx&=-\int_a^b {\partial \varphi\over \partial x}(x,t)\,dx+\int_a^b q(x,t)\,dx\\
    \int_a^b \left[{\partial u\over \partial t}(x,t)+{\partial \varphi\over \partial x}(x,t)\right]\,dx&=\int_a^b q(x,t)\,dx.
\end{align}

Since these integrals are equal for an arbitrary subinterval $[a,b]$ of $[\alpha,\beta]$, the integrands must be equal:
$$
{\partial u\over \partial t}(x,t)+{\partial \varphi\over \partial x}(x,t)=q(x,t).\tag{1}
$$
This is called the *Fundamental Conservation Law* because it applies to any scenario which obeys the conservation principle italicized above.

Of course this is not the heat equation---yet---because we need to impose one more assumption. Since $u(x,t)$ is the unknown we seek and $q(x,t)$ is the (known) source term, in order for solve for $u(x,t)$ we must know something about the flux $\varphi(x,t)$. In the context of heat diffusion, [Fourier's Law of heat conduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Fourier.27s_law) says that the flux of heat energy is proportional to, but in the opposite direction as, the gradient of the density: $\varphi=-k{\partial u\over \partial x}$ in this 1D context. Substituting this into (1),
$$
{\partial u\over\partial t}+{\partial\over \partial x}(-k\,u_x)=q(x,t),
$$
or the much more familiar form
$$
u_t=ku_{xx}+q(x,t)
$$
which is the *heat equation* in 1D (with a source term).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the way the problem is posed, it seems as if a good first step is to use the Fundamental theorem of Calculus to write $\varphi(b,t)$ as  $ \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \displaystyle\int_{a}^b \phi(x,t) dx$, but, for me, that made things much more complicated.

Instead, we can take $(2)$ and differentiate both sides with respect to $b$, getting $$ \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \displaystyle\int_a^b e(x,t) dx \right) = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( \varphi(a,t) \right) - \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b}  \left(\varphi(b,t) \right) + \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b}  \left( \displaystyle\int_a^b Q(x,t) dx \right) $$
On the lefthand side we can switch the order of the partial derivatives, and on the righthand side we note that $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( \varphi(a,t) \right) = 0$ because $a$ and $b$ are independent by assumption. This leaves us with $$ \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left( \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \displaystyle \int_a^b e(x,t) dx \right) = -\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left(\phi(b,t) \right) + \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b}  \left( \displaystyle\int_a^b Q(x,t) dx \right) $$
Applying the Fundamental theorem of Calculus to both sides gives $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(e(b,t) \right) =- \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial b} \left( \varphi(b,t) \right) + Q(b,t) $$
At this point $b$ is just an arbitrary position variable, and therefore we can replace $b$ by $x$ to obtain  $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(e(x,t) \right) = - \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \varphi(x,t) \right) + Q(x,t) $$

As shown in JohnD's answer, we can use Fourier's law of heat conduction to write $\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \varphi(x,t)$ as $- K_0(x) \displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$. This gives us the heat equation $$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(e(x,t) \right) = \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( K_0(x) \displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right) + Q(x,t) $$

Please note that this solution is based on techniques use on page 279 of Richard Haberman's book $\it{Mathematical \: Models}$, which is a great resource from which to learn a variety of tools for deriving ODEs and PDEs to model physical and biological situations.